# precision in xy axis in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, plot

I have this code

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5e-05,
ymin=1.222e-07,
ymax=1.224e-07
]
\addplot [color=red,line width=4.0pt,only marks,mark=*,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
1e-06   1.22231e-07 \\
2e-06   1.22234e-07 \\
3e-06   1.22239e-07 \\
4e-06   1.22246e-07 \\
5e-06   1.22255e-07 \\
6e-06   1.22266e-07 \\
7e-06   1.22279e-07 \\
8e-06   1.22294e-07 \\
9e-06   1.22311e-07 \\
1e-05   1.2233e-07  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%


    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
```

I call this in latex.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering 
  \setlength\figureheight{3in} 
  \setlength\figurewidth{2.5in} 
  \input{fit12.tex}
  \caption{ Figure}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I got this [image]

How can I replace "." with "x" and as you can see in y-axis , the three-sigfig is not enough for precision. How can I change the label precision? It could be great if the labeling can be readjust automatically like in matlab.

Comment: please provide a full MWE beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @Aung did you see the answers provided below?

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina Thanks. Can I apply `tick scale binop={\times}` for all figure as preamble?

Comment: @Aung Sure. Add `\pgfplotsset{tick scale binop={\times}}`
 to the preamble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, from the question, only the `\cdot` for the multiplier of the `y`-axis must bechanged, you can use

```
ytick scale label code/.code={$\times 10^{#1}$},
```

(the only change from the default definition is that `\cdot` was replaced by \times). If the \cdot of both axis multiplier is to be changed, you can change the definition of `tick scale binop` instead, using

```
tick scale binop={\times}
```

This can be made global for all plots by adding

```
\pgfplotsset{tick scale binop={\times}}
```

to the preamble.

To change the precision, you can use

```
/pgf/number format/precision=<value>
```

(the default `<value>` is three). A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1e-06   1.22229e-07 
2e-06   1.22234e-07 
3e-06   1.22239e-07 
4e-06   1.22246e-07 
5e-06   1.22255e-07 
6e-06   1.22266e-07 
7e-06   1.22279e-07 
8e-06   1.22294e-07 
9e-06   1.22311e-07 
1e-05   1.2233e-07  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
%width=\figurewidth,
%height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1.5e-05,
ymin=1.22224e-07,
ymax=1.2234e-07,
ytick =data,
ytick scale label code/.code={$\times 10^{#1}$},
/pgf/number format/precision=5
]
\addplot [color=red,line width=4.0pt,only marks,mark=*,mark options={solid},forget plot]
  table {data.dat};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now everything works out pretty well. I use like this `pgfplotsset{ticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=4}, tick scale binop={\times}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The first questions is answered by adding `tick scale binop=\times` to the `axis` options. All  the things you can with that number is described in the `pgfplots` manual section `Tick Scaling - Common Factors In Ticks`

working on the precision for the x ticks...